# PDO not working if I re-run a function inside itself

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm trying to create a system, where my website generates an unique code (current date + 5 random characters) and that code is transferred to a table in my database.

Before function generateNumber() can insert the unique code into the database, it has to check if the code already exist in the database.

If the code doesn't exist, my function works flawlessly. But the problem is when the code can already be found on the database, my website just doesn't do anything (it should just re-run the function).

```
function generateNumber()
{
    global $conn;

    $rand = strtoupper(substr(uniqid(sha1(time())),0,5));
    $result = date("Ydm") . $rand;

    $SQL = $conn->query("SELECT code FROM test WHERE code='$result'");
    $c = $SQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($c['code'] > 0) { // test if $result is already in the database
        generateNumber();
    } else {
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO test (code) VALUES (?)";
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
        $stmt2->execute([$result]);
        return $result;
    }
}

try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlite:db"/*, $username, $password*/);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    echo generateNumber();
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

There are no error messages in the console, but I suspect the problem is this part of the code:

```
if ($c['code'] > 0) { // test if $result is already in the database
    generateNumber();
}
```

Any idea how I can write this function in a better way?

Comment: Why is select not prepared and parametized?

Comment: You need to add return before you call your function recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
if ($c['code'] > 0) { // test if $result is already in the database
// if the code exists in db the function return nothing 
// because you are missing a return :
    return generateNumber();

}
```